# Show error on form submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I want to show an error using jQuery, there is no error checking yet, but I just want to learn more about jQuery and it seems like I can't get this working.

So, I want to show the error anyway when the submit button is pressed. I tried, to set visibility using jquery to visible onclick and invisible beforehand but it didn't work. It showed for a quick second and then it dissapeared. How can I make it show there until next submit buttonpress?

```
<form id="quick-register" action="">
    Username: <input type="text" name="quick-username"> <br>
    <span id="quick-user-wrong">Wrong Username (a-z, A-Z, 0-9)</span>

    Password: <input type="password" name="quick-password"> <br>
    <span id="quick-pass-wrong">Wrong Password</span>

    Repeat Password: <input type="password" name="quick-password2"> <br>
    <span id="quick-pass2-wrong">Password doesn't match</span>

    E-mail: <input type="email" name="quick-email"> <br>
    <span id="quick-email-wrong">Invalid E-mail Address</span>

    <button id="quick-submit">Register</button>
</form>
```

jQuery

```
$(function () {
    $("#quick-submit").one("click", function () {
        $("#quick-user-wrong").css("visibility", "visible");
    });
});
```

Comment: Post your jQuery code in here too

Comment: `$('#someID').show()` will show an element.  What did you try that isn't working?

Comment: Tried this: $(function() {            
            $("#quick-submit").one("click", function() {
                $("#quick-user-wrong").css("visibility", "visible");
            });
        });

Comment: Post it in your question, not the comments. You can edit your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create an event listener that will trigger on form submission, which you can cancel and submit at a later time.

```
$( "#quick-register" ).submit(function( e ) {
  //cancel submission
  e.preventDefault();

  // .... your error handling/etc ...

  if(noerror){
     //submit form later
     $(this).unbind("submit").submit();
  }

});
```

The problem at the moment is that the form is being submitted. This causes the page to refresh, which is why you only see your javascript work for a brief second.

Comment: Thank you, and how do I submit the form again on the next click? the one commented out doesnt work

Comment: @Trooper do you want it to only fail once, and not fail the second time? Or do you want it to fail as long as there are errors ( i.e. inputs are empty )

Comment: As long as there are errors I wan to fail, for now I would get pleased with an error if the input is empty, I will configure it more when I get down to do it more detailed, but I want to have the big idea first.

Comment: @Trooper see my edit. I forgot to do the unbind the first time around, which is why the form wouldn't submit afterwards. You'll need to determine what decides a 'no error' scenario. If you need more direction I can update my answer again.

Comment: @Trooper Take some time and work with AJAX using jQuery. http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/
Although it seems that you are new to jQuery, AJAX is not hard to handle, and would help you with what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

When you submit a form the page is reload afterwards (unless you are using AJAX)
It is beacause of this reload that the error is shown only a moment.
In your jQuery code

```
$("form").on('submit', function(evt){
   //if form errors
   evt.preventDefault();       
   //showerror
   //else do nothing
});
```

This will prevent the page to be submitted an therefore the error will be shown and remain showed

Therfore the user can change what is wrong and click again in submit button.